# UIBarButton Problem

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am having one problem with UIBarButtons in xCode iOS 4 with Objective-C.

I am following several examples and the error says that the addButtonPressed method was not defined - even though I have the function created before hand like this:

```
- (void)addButtonPressed
{
 NSLog(@"Addbutton pressed", @"");
}
```

It is also defined in the .h file. Here's my code:

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd  target:self action:addButtonPressed];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
 [addButton release];

Here's the error:

```
'addButtonPressed' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help,
Christian Stewart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a selector for the action argument instead of the method name.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed)];
```